# Gnome-tweaks not working

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and gnome-tweaks to make changes to my system. However, when I try to use it nothing changes in my system. I have tried rebooting my system and purging and reinstalling it, but nothing seems to keep working.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if it has a solution?

Comment: Are you using the GNOME desktop?  and can you please give some examples of changes you've made and what happened.  It's a bug only if reported on a bug-tracker.

Comment: I am using the Tweaks graphical application. Examples of things not working: middle-click paste, disable touchpad while not typing, suspend action when closing lid etc

Comment: Yes but it makes changes for the GNOME desktop, it won't do anything if you're not using the GNOME desktop.  I'm currently logged into LXQt, so any changes made in `gnome-tweaks` won't impact any of my GUI applications. Whilst I'm no expert (I'm not a big gnome fan), if you're using KDE/Qt based apps as make more sense on my LXQt desktop, gnome or GTK changes have little influence as the changes made impact gnome/GTK based apps.  Please add additional info to your question, not everyone reads comments

Answer (score 0):

First try to find what is going wrong. Run gnome-tweaks from terminal simply typing gnome-tweaks in the terminal. In Tweak will make some changes and see the log in the terminal. If it says

> Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

~/.config/dconf/user* files might have corrupted. Try the following command, it should recreate a new one and allow you to store your settings persistently:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak
```

Note that you may lose some customization that you may have set on your system as all of them will be reset.

If it does not solve your problem all you have to do is:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf.bak ~/.config/dconf/
```